# BlackBerry Recording Video Saves file of 0KB

Tags: video, blackberry, recording, video-player

I'm developing for BlackBerry and trying to record a video by not just launching the video camera app.

I can create the `Player` object and create a `Field` on screen that displays what the camera can see. I tried the recording and it works fine – but when I call `commit()` on the `RecordControl` a file is written to the SD Card of 0KB. I've been scratching my head at this for some time now and cannot solve this problem. Here is the code which starts and finishes the recording:

```
private void displayVideoRecorder()
{
    initVideoRecorder();

    if (mTimeLeft == null)
    {
        mTimeLeft = UIFactory.createLabel("Time left: " + (mMaxVideoDuration - mCurrVideoDuration));
    }

    // Create a stop recording button and a listener for the saving video functionality
    if (mStopRecording == null)
    {
        mStopRecording = UIFactory.createButtonField("Begin recording");
        mStopRecording.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener()
        {
            public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context)
            {
                if (mRecordingVideo)
                {
                    // Stop the messages
                    if (mHandlerID != -1)
                    {
                        UiApplication.getUiApplication().cancelInvokeLater(mHandlerID);
                        mHandlerID = -1;
                    }

                    new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            // Save the video
                            stopRecordingVideo();

                            // Reset the flag
                            mRecordingVideo = false;
                        }
                    }.run();

                    // Return to the main page
                    displayFirstPage();
                }
                else
                {
                    // Start recording
                    new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            mRecordControl.startRecord();
                            mRecordingVideo = true;

                            // Queue a message for however long the maximum time for a video is
                            mHandlerID = UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(mHandler, 1000, true);
                        }
                    }.run();

                    // Set a flag and change the text of the button
                    mStopRecording.setLabel("Stop recording");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    mCurrVideoDuration = 0;
    mStopRecording.setLabel("Begin recording");
    mTimeLeft.setText("Time left: " + (mMaxVideoDuration - mCurrVideoDuration));

    // Add the video & a button to go back
    getContentArea().deleteAll();
    getContentArea().add(mVideoField);
    getContentArea().add(mTimeLeft);
    getContentArea().add(mStopRecording);

    try
    {
        // Show what the camera can see
        mPlayer.start();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Out.p("Failed to begin video player");
        Out.printStackTrace(e);
    }
}

/**
 * Stops recording the video and saves the file to the file system. If a video is not recording this call is ignored
 */
private void stopRecordingVideo()
{
    if (mRecordingVideo)
    {
        try
        {
            mRecordingVideo = false;

            // Stop recording and save the file name
            mRecordControl.stopRecord();
            mPlayer.stop();

            mRecordControl.commit();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Out.alert(e.toString());
        }
    }
}

private void initVideoRecorder()
{
    try
    {
        Out.p("Beginning initialise of recorder");
        mPlayer = Manager.createPlayer("capture://video?" + getEncodings()[0]);// "capture://video?encoding=video/3gpp");

        mPlayer.addPlayerListener(new PlayerListener()
        {
            public void playerUpdate(Player player, String event, Object eventData)
            {
                Out.p("Player " + player.hashCode() + " got event " + event + ": " + eventData);
            }
        });

        mPlayer.realize();

        mVideoControl = (VideoControl) mPlayer.getControl("VideoControl");
        mRecordControl = (RecordControl) mPlayer.getControl("RecordControl");

        Out.p("Record Control: " + mRecordControl);

        // Set where the video will record to
        mRecordControl.setRecordLocation(mFilePath);

        mVideoField = (Field) mVideoControl.initDisplayMode(GUIControl.USE_GUI_PRIMITIVE, "net.rim.device.api.ui.Field");
        // add(mVideoField);

        Out.p("Video Field: " + mVideoField);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Out.alert(e.toString());
        Out.p("Failed to start recording");
        displayFirstPage();
    }
}
```

I've followed many guides after being able to get it to save an actual video, but there was no success. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
public class VideoRecordingApplication extends UiApplication

{

    /*

     * working constants hard coded to create video files on the SD media card

     */

    private static final String VIDEO_FILE = "file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/videos/mmapi_rimlet.3GP";

    private static final String STREAM_VIDEO_FILE = "file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/videos/mmapi_stream.sbv";

    /*

     * video recording screen object used in several places within

     */

    private static VideoRecordingScreen _vrs;

    /*

     * constructor

    */

    private VideoRecordingApplication()

    {

        /*

         * to select the video encoding

         */

        pushScreen( new ChooseEncodingScreen() );

    }

    /*

     * main() entry point

    */

    public static void main( String[] args )

    {

        /*

         * fire up the event dispatcher loop

         */

        new VideoRecordingApplication().enterEventDispatcher();

    }

    /*

     * select video encoding screen

     * called by the VideoRecordingApplication class constructor

     */

    private static final class ChooseEncodingScreen extends MainScreen

    {

        private static ObjectChoiceField _encodings;

        /*

         * constructor

         */

        public ChooseEncodingScreen()

        {

            super();

            setTitle( "Choose an encoding" );

            /*

             * load String[] array with all MMAPI video encoding system property values

             */

            String[] encodings = getEncodings();

            /*

             * prep for display

            */

            _encodings = new ObjectChoiceField( "Encoding:", encodings, 0 );

            /*

             * add field to this screen's manager

            */

            add( _encodings );

            /*

             * create a menu item to start recording using the selected encoding scheme

            */

            addMenuItem( new MenuItem( "Go", 0, 0 )

            {

                public void run()

                {

                    /*

                     * create and display the video recording screen, passing the selected video encoding scheme

                    */

                    _vrs = new VideoRecordingScreen( (String)_encodings.getChoice( _encodings.getSelectedIndex() ) );

                    UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen( _vrs );

                }

            } );

        }

        /*

         * returns all MMAPI video encoding system property values

         */

        private String[] getEncodings()

        {

            String[] encodings = new String[0];

            /*

             * load String with all video.encodings property values

             * each value is separated by a space

             */

            String encodingsString = System.getProperty( "video.encodings" );

            /*

             * determine where the first value ends

             */

            int space = encodingsString.indexOf( ' ' );

            /*

             * loop through values, end when a new field separator is not found

             */

            while( space != -1 )

            {

                /*

                 * add a new String array element that contains the system property value

                 */

                Arrays.add( encodings, encodingsString.substring( 0, space ) );

                /*

                 * remove the last property value from the encoding string

                 */

                encodingsString = encodingsString.substring( space + 1 );

                /*

                 * determine where the first value ends

                 */

                space = encodingsString.indexOf( ' ' );

            }

            /*

             * add a new String array element that contains the final system property value

             */

            Arrays.add( encodings, encodingsString );

            /*

             * return the resulting String[] array

             */

            return encodings;

        }

    }

    /*

     * video recording screen displayed after the user selects "Go" from the menu

     */

    private static final class VideoRecordingScreen extends MainScreen

    {

        private static Player _player;

        private static VideoControl _vc;

        private static RecordControl _rc;

        private static boolean _visible = true;

        private static boolean _locationSet = false;

        private static RichTextField _status;

        private static CheckboxField _stream;

        private static OutputStream _out;

        private static FileConnection _fc;

        private static RichTextField _flashIndicator;

        /*

         * constructor passed the chosen video encoding property value

         */

        public VideoRecordingScreen( String encoding )

        {

            super();

            try {

                /*

                 * create a video media player to capture video using the passed encoding value

                 */

                _player = javax.microedition.media.Manager.createPlayer( "capture://video?" + encoding );

                /*

                 * try to start the player

                 */

                _player.start();

                _vc = (VideoControl)_player.getControl( "VideoControl" );

                _rc = (RecordControl)_player.getControl( "RecordControl" );

                /*

                 * Initialize the mode on how the video is displayed.

                 * This method must be called before the video can be displayed.

                 *

                 * USE_GUI_PRIMITIVE defines a mode on how the GUI is displayed.

                 * It is used in conjunction with initDisplayMode(int, java.lang.Object).

                 */

                Field videoField = (Field)_vc.initDisplayMode( GUIControl.USE_GUI_PRIMITIVE, "net.rim.device.api.ui.Field" );

                /*

                 * add field to this screen's manager

                 */

                add( videoField );

                _status = new RichTextField( "Idle" );

                add( _status );

                _stream = new CheckboxField( "Use OutputStream", false );

                add( _stream );

            } catch ( Exception e ) {

                System.out.println( "Exception in VideoScreen constructor" );

            }

            addMenuItem( new MenuItem( "Start Record", 0, 0 )

            {

                public void run()

                {

                    startRecord();

                }

            } );

            addMenuItem( new MenuItem( "Stop Record", 0, 0 )

            {

                public void run()

                {

                    stopRecord();

                }

            } );

            addMenuItem( new MenuItem( "Commit Record", 0, 0 )

            {

                public void run()

                {

                    commit();

                }

            } );

            addMenuItem( new MenuItem( "Toggle Visibility", 0, 0 )

            {

                public void run()

                {

                    toggleVisibility();

                }

            } );

            addMenuItem( new MenuItem( "Play Recording", 0, 0 )

            {

                public void run()

                {

                    //InputStream recording = _stream.getChecked() ? new ByteArrayInputStream( _out.toByteArray() ) : null;

                    Application.getApplication().invokeLater( new ShowVideoRunnable( null ) );

                }

            } );

            /*

             * this loads the streamed video into memory then does nothing with it

             */

            addMenuItem( new MenuItem( "Analyze Recording Stream", 0, 0 )

            {

                public void run()

                {

                    try {

                        /*

                         * get a handle to the streaming video file located on the SDCard (declared near the start of this file)

                         */

                        _fc = (FileConnection)Connector.open( STREAM_VIDEO_FILE );

                        /*

                         * determine the file size

                         */

                        long size = _fc.fileSize();

                        /*

                         * declare a block of ram to store the file

                         */

                        byte[] file = new byte[(int)size];

                        /*

                         * open the stream for read

                         */

                        InputStream in = _fc.openInputStream();

                        /*

                         * load the file into memory

                         */

                        in.read( file );

                    } catch ( Exception e ) {

                    }

                }

            } );

        }

        /*

         * decipher and act upon shortcut keys

         */

        protected boolean keyChar( char c, int status, int time )

        {

            switch( c ) {

                case 's':

                    startRecord();

                    return true;

                case 'x':

                    stopRecord();

                    return true;

                case 'c':

                    commit();

                    return true;

                case 'v':

                    toggleVisibility();

                    return true;

                case 'r':

                    reset();

                    return true;

                default:

                    return false;

            }

        }

        /*

         * record captured video

         */

        private void startRecord()

        {

            try {

                /*

                 * _locationSet == false by default

                 */

                if( !_locationSet )

                {

                    /*

                     * test if "Use OutputStream" CheckboxField is set

                     */

                    if( _stream.getChecked() )

                    {

                        try {

                            _fc = (FileConnection)Connector.open( VIDEO_FILE );

                            /*

                             * create streaming file if it does not exist

                             */

                            if( !_fc.exists() )

                            {

                                _fc.create();

                            }

                            /*

                             * zap the file

                             */

                            _fc.truncate( 0 );

                            /*

                             * ready to write video stream

                             */

                            _out = _fc.openOutputStream();

                        } catch ( Exception e ) {

                            return;

                        }

                        _rc.setRecordStream( _out );

                    } else {

                        /*

                         * FileConnection: Set the output stream where the data will be recorded.

                         * The locator specifying where the recorded media will be saved.

                         * The locator must be specified as a URL.

                         */

                        _rc.setRecordLocation( VIDEO_FILE );

                    }

                    _locationSet = true;

                }

                /*

                 * Start recording the media.

                 */

                _rc.startRecord();

                _status.setText( "Recording" );

            } catch ( Exception e ) {

            }

        }

        private void stopRecord()

        {

            try {

                /*

                 * Stop recording the media.

                 * stopRecord will not automatically stop the Player.

                 * It only stops the recording, putting the Player in "standby" mode

                 */

                _rc.stopRecord();

                _status.setText( "Recording stopped" );

            } catch ( Exception e ) {

            }

        }

        private void commit()

        {

            try {

                /*

                 * Complete the current recording.

                 * If the recording is in progress, commit will implicitly call stopRecord.

                 */

                _rc.commit();

                Dialog.alert( "Committed" );

                _locationSet = false;

                _status.setText( "Committed" );

                /*

                 * video stream was recorded

                 */

                if( _stream.getChecked() )

                {

                    /*

                     * close the stream

                     */

                    try {

                        _out.close();

                        _fc.close();

                    } catch ( Exception e ) {

                    }

                }

            } catch ( Exception e ) {

            }

        }

        /*

         * toggle video visibility

         */

        private void toggleVisibility()

        {

            try {

                _visible = !_visible;

                /*

                 * show or hide the video

                 */

                _vc.setVisible( _visible );

            } catch ( Exception e ) {

            }

        }

        /*

         * Erase the current recording

         */

        private void reset()

        {

            try {

                _rc.reset();

                _status.setText( "Reset called, idle" );

            } catch ( Exception e ) {

            }

        }

        /*

         * hide the video

         */

        public void hide()

        {

            try {

                _visible = false;

                _vc.setVisible( _visible );

            } catch ( Exception e ) {

            }

        }

        /*

         * show the video

         */

        public void show()

        {

            try {

                _visible = true;

                _vc.setVisible( _visible );

            } catch ( Exception e ) {

            }

        }

    }

    /*

     * ShowVideoRunnable() called within VideoRecordingScreen() through the "Play Recording" menu

     */

    private static final class VideoPlaybackScreen extends MainScreen

    {

        private Player _video;

        private VideoControl _vc;

        public VideoPlaybackScreen( InputStream vid )

        {

            super();

            try {

                /*

                 * existing video stream passed

                 */

                if( vid != null )

                {

                    /*

                     * Create a Player to play back media from an InputStream (streamed video)

                     */

                    _video = javax.microedition.media.Manager.createPlayer( vid, "video/x-rim" );

                } else {

                    /*

                     * Create a Player from an input locator (a standard video file in .3GP format)

                     */

                    _video = javax.microedition.media.Manager.createPlayer( VIDEO_FILE );

                }

                /*

                 * Constructs portions of the Player without acquiring the scarce and exclusive resources.

                 */

                _video.realize();

                /*

                 * Obtain the object that implements the specified Control interface.

                 */

                _vc = (VideoControl)_video.getControl( "VideoControl" );

                /*

                 * Initialize the mode on how the video is displayed

                 */

                Field vField = (Field)_vc.initDisplayMode( GUIControl.USE_GUI_PRIMITIVE, "net.rim.device.api.ui.Field" );

                add( vField );

                VolumeControl vol = (VolumeControl)_video.getControl( "VolumeControl" );

                vol.setLevel( 30 );

            } catch ( Exception e ) {

                System.out.println( "Exception while showing video" );

            }

        }

        protected void onVisibilityChange( boolean visible )

        {

            if( visible ) {

                try {

                    /*

                     * Starts the Player as soon as possible.

                     */

                    _video.start();

                } catch ( Exception e ) {

                }

            }

        }

        public boolean onClose() {

            try {

                /*

                 * Close the Player and release its resources.

                 */

                _video.close();

            } catch ( Exception e ) {

            }

            _vrs.show();

            return super.onClose();

        }

    }

    /*

     * called within VideoRecordingScreen() through the "Play Recording" menu

     */

    private static final class ShowVideoRunnable implements Runnable

    {

        private InputStream _in;

        public ShowVideoRunnable( InputStream in )

        {

            _in = in;

        }

        public void run()

        {

            /*

             * hide the VideoRecordingScreen

             */

            _vrs.hide();

            /*

             * Retrieves this UI application object.

             */

            UiApplication ui = UiApplication.getUiApplication();

            /*

             * handle video playback

             */

            ui.pushScreen( new VideoPlaybackScreen( _in ) );

        }

    }

}
```